# How to test a method where the set up and checking depends on untested methods?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've created an example class (a bitmask class) which has 4 really simple functions. I've also created a unit-test for this class.

```
import unittest

class BitMask:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__mask = 0

    def set(self, slot):
        self.__mask |= (1 << slot)

    def remove(self, slot):
        self.__mask &= ~(1 << slot)

    def has(self, slot):
        return (self.__mask >> slot) & 1

    def clear(self):
        self.__mask = 0


class TestBitmask(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.bitmask = BitMask()

    def test_set_on_valid_input(self):
        self.bitmask.set(5)
        self.assertEqual(self.bitmask.has(5), True)

    def test_has_on_valid_input(self):
        self.bitmask.set(5)
        self.assertEqual(self.bitmask.has(5), True)

    def test_remove_on_valid_input(self):
        self.bitmask.set(5)
        self.bitmask.remove(5)
        self.assertEqual(self.bitmask.has(5), False)

    def test_clear(self):
        for i in range(16):
            self.bitmask.set(i)
        self.bitmask.clear()
        for j in range(16):
            with self.subTest(j=j):
                self.assertEqual(self.bitmask.has(j), False)
```

The problem I'm facing is that all these tests requires both the `set` and `has` methods for setting and checking values in the bitmask, but these methods are untested. I cannot confirm that one is correct without knowing that the other one is.

This example class isn't the first time I've experienced this issue. It usually occurs when I need to set up and check values/states within a class in order to test a method.

I've tried to find resources that explain this, but unfortunately their examples only [use](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/09/improve-your-python-understanding-unit-testing/) [pure](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/simple-test.html) [functions](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/) or where the changed attribute can be [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602.aspx#BKMK_Writing_your_tests) [directly](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/write-professional-unit-tests-in-python--cms-25835). I could solve the problem by extracting the methods to be pure functions, or using a read-only property that returns the attribute `__mask`.

But is this the preferred approach? If not, how do I test a method that needs to be set up and/or checked using untested methods?

Comment: how does `self.subTest(j=j)` work?

Comment: @Evgeny It just give a message on which j-value the assert method fails on (if it fails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would’ve used single underscore instead of double, and just looked directly at the `_mask` in unit test.

Python doesn’t really have private attributes or methods, even double underscore attributes are accessible on your instance like this: `obj._BitMask__mask`. 
Double underscore is used when you want subclasses to not overwrite the attribute of superclass. To indicate “private” you should use single underscore.

Allowing access to private fields is a part of python's design, so using this ability [responsibly](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#we-are-all-responsible-users) is not considered wrong, doubly so if you are accessing *your own* class.

The rationale behind "Do not touch the private fields" is that you as the developer can mess something up with the internals of the class, also private interface of s library can change at any point and break your code. 
When you are writing unit tests you are not afraid of messing with your own class, and is accepting that you have to change unit test if you change your class, so this programming idiom is not useful for you to apply.

Comment: Considering that unit-testing is applicable to all languages, I would suspect that there would be a suggested approach that isn't dependent on the specific implementation of Python. The fact that Python is dynamic, has much metadata and that everything is public, it's possible to use this to solve problem like these, but I'm more looking for the preferred design choice when constructing classes and/or unit-tests in general.

Comment: I am not aware of some general method, but considering that even in C# private method(and, I suspect, property) testing [requires introspection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184807(v=vs.80).aspx) there is no clean way to do this.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical considering [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811167/6486738) that suggest that testing using introspection for my own code is considered flaws in my design. Which is why I feel like introspection probably isn't the right choice for me, but rather that it's something I should change by my design. As one choice is to make the mask available as a read-only property, but I'm still hesitant if it's good to practice to make internal variables readable.

Comment: This idea is expressed in the phrase [we are all responsible users](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#we-are-all-responsible-users).  If your property is not a part of your interface - mark it private. But if for testing purposes you need to access `._mask` - it's your code, do whatever you need. Also I'd like to remind you of mocking - literally monkey patching libraries - this is standard tool of unit testing and a huge no-no in regular programming. And finally, look for `._` in unit tests of big python projects (requests, django, ...), you'll see plenty.

Comment: After reading up on this it seems like reading the "private" attribute is more or less the way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this answers your question, as it deals with changing of initial class design,
but here it goes.

You make a lazy class with no constructor or property , which hides the state of your 
object. It is not the `set` or `has` methods that are untested, it is the issue of 
state of the object being unknown. Have you had a `.value` property to reveal 
`self.__mask`, this would solve a question of testing .set() and has().

Also I would strongly consider a default value in constructor, which makes it a better-looking 
instantination and allows easier testing (some advice on avoiding setters in python [is here](https://gist.github.com/sloria/7001839)).

```
def __init__(self, mask=0):
    self.__mask = mask
```

If there any design considerations that prevent you from having a `.value` property, 
perhaps an `__eq__ method can be used, if __init__ accepts a value.

```
 a = BitMask(0)     
 b = BitMask(5)     
 a.set(5)
 assert a == b
```

Of course, you can challenge that on how is __eq__tested itself.

Finally, perhaps you are failiar with *patching* or *monkey-patching* - a 
technique to block something inside a object under test or make it work differently 
(eg imitate web response without actual call). With any of the libraries for pathcing 
I think you would still endup-performing a `kind of` `x.__mask = value` assignment, which 
is not too reasonable for a small, nice, and locally-defined class like one here.

Hope it helps in line of what you are exploring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems like I have to go on the simplest approach of just accessing the private attribute

Comment: It is a very sensible thing to do!